# Best way to structure relationships in a no-SQL database?

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDB. I know that MongoDB isn't relational but information sometimes is. So what's the most efficient way to reference these kinds of relationships to lessen database load and maximize query speed?

Example:

*** Tinder-style "matches" ***

There are many users in a Users collection. They get matched to each other.

So I'm thinking:

```
Document 1:

{
    _id: "d3fg45wr4f343",
    firstName: "Bob",
    lastName: "Lee",
    matches: [
      "ferh823u9WURF",
      "8Y283DUFH3FI2",
      "KJSDH298U2F8",
      "shdfy2988U2Ywf"
    ]
}
```

Document 2:

```
{
    _id: "d3fg45wr4f343",
    firstName: "Cindy",
    lastName: "Doe",
    matches: [
      "d3fg45wr4f343"
    ]
}
```

Would this work OK if there were, say, 10,000 users and you were on Bob's profile page and you wanted to display the firstName of all of his matches?

Any alternative structures that would work better?

*** Online Forum ***

I supposed you could have the following collections:

Users

Topics

Users Collection:

```
{
  _id: "d3fg45wr4f343",
  userName: "aircon",
  avatar: "234232.jpg"
}

{
  _id: "23qdf3a3fq3fq3",
  userName: "spider",
  avatar: "986754.jpg"
}
```

Topics Collection Version 1

One example document in the Topics Collection:

```
{
title: "A spider just popped out of the AC",
dateTimeSubmitted: 201408201200,
category: 5,
posts: [
    {
        message: "I'm going to use a gun.",
        dateTimeSubmitted: 201408201200,
        author: "d3fg45wr4f343"
    },
    {
        message: "I don't think this would work.",
        dateTimeSubmitted: 201408201201,
        author: "23qdf3a3fq3fq3"
    },
    {
        message: "It will totally work.",
        dateTimeSubmitted: 201408201202,
        author: "d3fg45wr4f343"
    },
    {
        message: "ur dumb",
        dateTimeSubmitted: 201408201203,
        author: "23qdf3a3fq3fq3"
    }
]
}
```

Topics Collection Version 2

One example document in the Topics Collection. The author's avatar and userName are now embedded in the document. I know that:

This is not DRY.

If the author changes their avatar and userName, these change would need to be updated in the Topics Collection and in all of the post documents that are in it.

BUT it saves the system from querying for all the avatars and userNames via the authors ID every single time this thread is viewed on the client.

```
{
title: "A spider just popped out of the AC",
dateTimeSubmitted: 201408201200,
category: 5,
posts: [
    {
        message: "I'm going to use a gun.",
        dateTimeSubmitted: 201408201200,
        author: "d3fg45wr4f343",
        userName: "aircon",
        avatar: "234232.jpg"
    },
    {
        message: "I don't think this would work.",
        dateTimeSubmitted: 201408201201,
        author: "23qdf3a3fq3fq3",
        userName: "spider",
        avatar: "986754.jpg"
    },
    {
        message: "It will totally work.",
        dateTimeSubmitted: 201408201202,
        author: "d3fg45wr4f343",
        userName: "aircon",
        avatar: "234232.jpg"
    },
    {
        message: "ur dumb",
        dateTimeSubmitted: 201408201203,
        author: "23qdf3a3fq3fq3",
        userName: "spider",
        avatar: "986754.jpg"
    }
]
}
```

So yeah, I'm not sure which is best...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data is realy many to many i.e. one can have many matches and can be matched by many in your first example it is usually best to go with relations.

The main arguments against relations stem from mongodb not beeing a relational database so there are no such things as foreign key constraints or join statements.

The trade off you have to consider in those many to many cases (many beeing much more than two) is either enforce the key constraints yourself or manage the possible data inconsistencies accross the multiple documents (your last example). And in most cases the relational approach is much more practical than the embedding approach for those cases.

Exceptions could be read often write seldom examples. For (a very constructed) example when in your first example matches would be recalculated once a day or so by wiping all previous matches and calculating a list of new matches. In that case the data inconsistencies you would introduce could be acceptable and the read time you save by embedding the firstnames of the matches could be an advantage.

But usually for many to many relations it would be best to use a relational approach and make use of the array query features such as `{_id :{$in:[matches]}}`.

But in the end it all comes down to the consideration of how many inconsistencies you can live with and how fast you realy need to access the data (is it ok for some topics to have the old avatar for a few days if I save half a second of page load time?).

---

**Edit**

The schema design series on the mongodb blog might be a good read for you: [part1](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1), [part2](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87892923503/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2) and [part3](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/88473035333/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3)